# Return generic length tuple of values with inference

Tags: c++, sql, templates, tuples

I am having a problem figuring out how to do some template magic. What I would like to do is pass a function a list of types.

```
function<int, std::string, int>(); //no parameters
```

then have it return a tuple of those types

```
std::tuple<int, std::string, int> x;
```

I plan to fill the tuple with the `query.getColumn` function from the SQLiteCPP library "https://github.com/SRombauts/SQLiteCpp". That function returns a different type based on the query. The end goal is to have the tuple filled with the values of the columns.

All of the examples I have seen in relation to similar things are in the form of parameter packs. Parameter packs work for passing values to a function but not getting a specific type out. I assume I will have to do something similar to input the values though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like below ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename... Args>
std::tuple<Args...> func() {
  std::tuple<Args...> x;
  return x;
}

int main() {
  auto r = func<int, char>();
  std::cout << typeid(r).name() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

It will give below output :

```
./auto_tuple | c++filt -t
std::tuple<int, char>
```

I may have misunderstood your question, in that case let me know (I should delete it in that case)

Comment: Why not use directly `std::tuple<Args...>` instead of `decltype` (and you use it for `x` anyway) ?

Comment: <facepalm> time to question my sanity. Thanks. Now I doubt whether I have answered the question correct :P.

Comment: I think that OP thinks (wrongly) that template parameter pack can only be deduced from arguments. Your code answers the question.